# BelongsToMany retrieving and deleting correctly, not updating/saving in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0, model-associations

CakePHP 3.8.13 - I have a table model which CAN retrieve the related data from a table and remove it, but when updating/adding an entry, it does not change this data for some reason. So it seems like a correct setup, yet it does not update/add them. In short, it's a "Questions" table and a "Divisions" table, with a relation table called "questions_divisions". In this relation table there is a question_id and a division_id column. If I manually add or remove entries there, it all seems OK. Just when doing patchEntity and save, it does not do it. This is the post data:

```
  'name' => string 'Some name' (length=8)
  'questiontype_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'extra' => string '' (length=0)
  'answer' => string '' (length=0)
  'datafield' => string 'Person.firstname' (length=16)
  'divisions' => 
    array (size=1)
      '_ids' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string '7' (length=1)
          2 => string '5' (length=1)
```

This is the code that is executed (so the above post data, is $this->request->getData()):

```
$question = $this->Questions->patchEntity($question, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Questions->save($question)) {
```

All this is more or less the same that's happening elsewhere in the application for a different model, which actually DOES add/update the divisions. I also cleared the /tmp/cache just in case, didn't seem to do the trick. I'm at a loss here.

This is the whole table model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Questions Model
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\QuestiontypesTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Questiontypes
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ActivitiesTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Activities
 * @property \App\Model\Table\BookingformsTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Bookingforms
 * @property \App\Model\Table\DivisionsTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Divisions
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question|bool save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question|bool saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Question findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 */
class QuestionsTable extends Table {

    public function beforeFind ($event, $query, $options, $primary) {
        $order = $query->clause('order');
        if ($order === null || !count($order)) {
            $query->order([$this->getAlias() . '.name' => 'ASC']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('questions');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Search.Search');
        $this->addBehavior('Page');

        $this->hasMany('Questions_divisions', [
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('Questiontypes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'questiontype_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Activities', [
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'activity_id',
            'joinTable' => 'activities_questions'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Bookingforms', [
            'foreignKey' => 'questions_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'bookingforms_id',
            'joinTable' => 'questions_bookingforms'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Divisions', [
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'division_id',
            'joinTable' => 'questions_divisions'
        ]);

        //Setup searchfield
        $this->behaviors()->Page->searchSetup($this->behaviors()->Search->searchManager(), $this->searchForm());
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
        $validator
                ->integer('id')
                ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
                ->scalar('name')
                ->maxLength('name', 500)
                ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('name');

        $validator
                ->scalar('extra')
                ->maxLength('extra', 500)
                ->allowEmpty('extra');

        $validator
                ->scalar('answer')
                ->maxLength('answer', 1500)
                ->allowEmpty('answer');

        $validator
                ->scalar('datafield')
                ->maxLength('datafield', 500)
                ->requirePresence('datafield', 'create')
                ->notEmpty('datafield');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules) {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['questiontype_id'], 'Questiontypes'));

        return $rules;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array which describes the search form
     *
     * @return Array with search setup
     */
    public function searchForm() {
        //Set up search form
        $search_data = [['id' => 'name', 'label' => 'Naam', 'type' => 'textfield', 'fields' => ['name']],
            ['id' => 'Questiontypes_id', 'label' => 'Vraagtype', 'type' => 'multiselect', 'fields' => ['Questiontypes.id'], 'options' => $this->Questiontypes->find('list')],
            ['id' => 'datafield', 'label' => 'Dataveld', 'type' => 'textfield', 'fields' => ['datafield']]
        ];
        return $search_data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Start with debugging `$question` before and after patching. Also please explain what exactly is happening when saving, from your explanation it's unclear whether only parts of the data is not being saved, or nothing is being saved at all.

Comment: @ndm Sorry for not being fully clear here. Everything gets saved correctly, without the extra added "divisions". That's the belongsToMany('Divisions') bit. It DOES actually retrieve it. Upon saving, the divisions (when manually added) is both before and after the path/save available. Only just not as how I edited them. So if I send 3 ids as divisions like the post data above, it still only gets the 1 from the database... For some reason, it wouldn't let me update it but only retrieve (and when doing a delete(), it will get deleted from the relation table too).

Comment: And what does `$question` look like before and after patching? In particular, what's in the `divisions` property, and is that property flagged as dirty?

Comment: Thanks @GregSchmidt, your debugging got me for looking further into this model and saw that accessible needed this column name too. That's what I actually forgot to add it seems and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding this column in the $_accessible array (inside the Model/Entity) does the trick... That's why it could retrieve the data, but not edit it - hence "accessible" maybe? Not sure if that's the correct name for it but hey..

```
protected $_accessible = [
   'name' => true,
   'extra' => true,
   'answer' => true,
   'datafield' => true,
   'questiontype_id' => true,
   'questiontype' => true,
   'activities' => true,
   'bookingforms' => true,
   'divisions' => true // this did the trick!
];
```